# Cisco unified connections subnetting

Tags: cisco, vlan, subnet

I need some clarification when using Cisco unified connections as a basis for my VoIP network. If I have a PC connecting through an IP phone, how can I put the PC into a separate subnet? If the IP phone and PC are separate subnets, how would they be able to communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

as shown in the figure , the layer 2 switch will be connected to the ip phone with connection called ***mini trunk*** which acting as a trunk carry two Vlan's the data one and the voice one . on the ip phone itself there is mini switch which will untag the voice vlan and use it for voice traffic and untag the data vlan and forward it to the pc port . voice traffic is treated this way mainly for one reason that is QOS ,where voice traffic need to be prioritized than the data traffic

Answer (score 2):

The switch will use either CDP or LLDP to negotiate a trunk with the phone. The VoIP phone acts as a switch. As with any VLANs, you need a router to let a device on one VLAN talk to a device on another VLAN. The PC and phone probably have no need to communicate with each other. It is normally a good idea to keep VoIP and data VLANs separate.

For a Cisco switch, you put this on an access port:

```
switchport access vlan <DATA VLAN>
switchport voice vlan <VOIP VLAN>
switchport mode access
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Maupin stated, VOIP and data traffic are typically separated. The Phone acting as a Switch (layer 2 device), will just pass the IP traffic from the Phone and PC to the router for Layer 3 (routing) functionality. Therefore, the networks that each device is in (whether it is the same or not) does not matter to the Phone or PC.